# How to get data with passing parameter in android retrofit kotlin

Tags: kotlin, post, get, retrofit

I want to pass String parameter to the interface and get String data processed with String I passed.

But I can't response.isSuccessful == true.

"/danmun/m" is get one String parameter and return String data.

How can I get the processed String data which I passed.

```
interface Danmun_processing {
        @GET("http://118.67.123.8/danmun/m")
        fun getDataParam(@Query("param1") param1 : String): Call<String>
}
val danmunProcessing = retrofit.create(Danmun_processing::class.java)

val sentence = "sample string data"

danmunProcessing.getDataParam(sentence).enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
     override fun onResponse(
           call: Call<String>,
           response: Response<String>
     ) {
     if(response.isSuccessful) {

     }
     else {

     }
}     
override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {

}

})
```

I want to get the processed String data with using data I passed.

Comment: `But I can't response.isSuccessful == true.` - do you mean `response.isSuccessful` evaluates to false when you execute the code? That means your server is returning an error, you'd need to find out why that happens.

Comment: This code makes response.code 500 error.